# gRPC build error using Visual Studio 2019 C#

Tags: c#, grpc

[image]

I make my project based on this tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/grpc/grpc-start?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

It told me that it is missing directive or an assembly reference. 
But I instal the related plugin, and the code generate successfully, I don't know why VS still can't find the code...
Here is the code content, the namespace is exist:

[image]

More info my proto properties:
[image]

Error Msg:

> 1>MainWindow.xaml.cs(6,7,6,23): error CS0246: The type or namespace
>   name 'HeartBeatMessage' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)
>   1>MainWindow.xaml.cs(16,24,16,40): error CS0246: The type or namespace
>   name 'HeartBeatService' could not be found (are you missing a using
>   directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this question because I was running into this problem too. See: https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20402

For now, I have manually moved the generated .cs files into my project and disabled the build step on the .proto (otherwise VS will complain about double definitions).